# Dovecot. Why do we need a public namespace?

Tags: dovecot, imap

I'm really confused about namespaces.
Here's the Dovecot tutorial I'm trying to follow:

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/VirtualUserFlatFilesPostfix

Can someone explain to me what exactly is being accomplished by publish namespace there?

Does it mean that all accounts from all domains can use /var/vmail/public ? I don't get it...

Comment: Probably better addressed in SuperUser SE

Comment: @mdpc: why superuser? This is an imap server, not client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that all accounts from all domains can use /var/vmail/public ?

Yes. Public namespaces are namespaces that are shared by multiple users. You can find more information about them [here](http://wiki.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes/Public).

Comment: It's not clear from dovcot example how does mail appear in public namespace in the first place?

Comment: Just like with "regular" private namespaces, it can either get delivered into the public namespace (possible example use case: a mailing list), or else users can move/copy it there from other mailboxes (if they have write permission to the public namespace).